# Should questions related to Git be asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have seen quite some questions regarding the usage of [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) (distributed revision control and source code management). Is this because of historic reasons or should Stack Overflow be a place to ask about Git?

Comment: See ["Are git related questions “on-topic” on Stack Overflow?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136920/are-git-related-questions-on-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Why was that older question moved Meta Stack Exchange, wouldn't it be more appropriate here?

Comment: @sashoalm: Every question that was posted prior to the split was automatically relocated there. The ones that are specific to Stack Overflow just need to be moved back here.

Comment: See [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/27077).

Comment: See also [Are git related questions “on-topic” on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255429/456814).

Comment: Git? No, that's not appropriate anywhere. Mercurial on the otherhand ...

Answer (score 15):

The FAQ clearly states that questions about tools used by programmers, such as IDEs, etc., are also acceptable. Git would fall into that category.

Comment: thanks. I was a bit unsure. Now I feel encouraged to ask

Comment: Though I can no longer find any mention, may be they removed it...

Comment: It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic