# Are Git-related questions "on-topic" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

It seems to me that a lot of the [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) questions on Stack Overflow are off-topic and do not really belong on a website about coding.

Is there another Stack Exchange site that they could be moved to?

Comment: Why are they off topic? Last time I checked, it was programmers that used [tag:git], not [cyclists](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), and the FAQ states (under the heading of ["What question can I ask here"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)) that you can ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: @Matt because git is usally on the server, not having to do with any code. So maybe they belong on SU?

Comment: Git is not *usually on a server*. Granted it has nothing to do with code, but as said, tools used by programmers are **on-topic** on SO.

Comment: git is a source control tool - questions about source control and the tools we use to manage source control are totally and absolutely on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See also [Should questions related to Git be asked on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255038/456814).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Of course they are on topic. Per the FAQ:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Emphasis mine

Comment: Hmmmmm FAQ Shmaq, you ***may*** be right.

Comment: I think it is a very thin line. E.g. I would say [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157060/github-can-i-offer-access-to-compiled-files-without-versioning-them) is off topic. Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: @PeeHaa - meh - I'm not really a GIT person -- the community seems to have viewed that question favorably though.  If it were up to me I'd just leave it alone.

Answer (score 11):

Not only are they on topic per the FAQ, they *should continue to be* on topic because source control is such an integrated part of software development.

If anything we need to get *more* people to discover source control tools, and what way is better than having a visible support platform where the questions are welcome? Everybody in this profession should know these tools.